# Selenium WebDriver (C#). Drag and drop of an element into iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with C# for automation. But recently I faced a problem with dragging an element from outside an iframe and dropping it on another element (or place) inside an iframe. I was trying to perform drag and drop by existing methods of `Actions` class: (in the examples below `source` is placed outside the iframe, but `target` - inside.)

1. `DragAndDrop(IWebElement source, IWebElement target)`. Here I still get a `StaleElementException` due to needing to switch to `iframe`.
2. `DragAndDropToOffset(IWebElement source, int offsetX, int offsetY)`. In this case nothing happens at all.

I am providing snippet of my code:

```
var source = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(
    "//div[@data-window-module-name='Sitemap'];
var actions= new Actions(Driver);
Driver.SwitchToFrame("WVTemplateFrame");
var target = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@name='WVTemplateFrame']//a");
Driver.SwitchToDefaultContent();
actions.DragAndDrop(source, target).Build().Perform();
[or]
actions.DragAndDropToOffset(source, 120, 206).Build().Perform();
```

Both examples do not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code i used that worked for me:

```
    internal void DragCardFromColumnToColumn(int p0, int p1)
    {
        var columns = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("column"));
        var cardHeader = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("portlet-header"));

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

        IAction dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(cardHeader)
           .MoveToElement(columns[0])
           .Release(columns[1])
           .Build();

        dragAndDrop.Perform();
    }
```